# Неправильно переносятся блоки

Tags: html, css

Проблема такая , блок переносится вниз хотя должен быть напротив высокого блока , вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а у меня переносится вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код:

```css
.lessons__block-wide{
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 30px 0px rgba(75, 63, 96, 0.15);
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 560px;
  padding: 22px 30px 24px 30px;
  position: relative;
}
.lessons__years{
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 120%;
  letter-spacing: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgb(100, 60, 193);
  width: 70px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  margin-bottom: 29px;
}
.lessons__title{
  color: rgb(13, 2, 34);
  font-family: Circe Rounded ;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 120%;
  letter-spacing: 0%;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  width: 210px;
}
.lessons__link{
  color: rgb(88, 81, 101);
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 150%;
  letter-spacing: 0%;
  text-align: left;
}

.lesson__image{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.lessons__blocks{
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 560px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 40px 0px;
}
.lessons__block-small{
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 30px 0px rgba(75, 63, 96, 0.15);
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 260px;
  padding: 22px 30px 24px 30px;
  position: relative;
}
.lessons__block-high{
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 30px 0px rgba(75, 63, 96, 0.15);
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 260px;
  padding: 22px 30px 22px 30px;
  min-height: 460px;
  position: relative;
  }
  .lessons__block-high .lesson__image{
  height: 274px;
  top: auto;
  }
  .lessons__content{
    display: flex;
    gap: 0 40px;
    align-items: start;
  }
```

```html
    <section class="lessons">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="lessons__content">
                <div class="lessons__blocks">
                    <div class="lessons__block-wide">
                        <img class="lesson__image" src="static/imgs/lesson__1.svg" alt="">
                        <p class="lessons__years">4-8 лет</p>
                        <h2 class="lessons__title">Английский<br> для малышей</h2>
                        <a class="lessons__link" href="#">Узнать больше <svg width="26.200195" height="9.003906" viewBox="0 0 26.2002 9.00391" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                            <defs/>
                            <path id="Vector 156" d="M0.5 4.50195L25.5 4.50195M21.5786 8.50195L25.5 4.50195L21.5786 0.501953" stroke="#585165" stroke-opacity="1.000000" stroke-width="1.000000"/>
                        </svg>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="lessons__block-small">
                        <img class="lesson__image" src="static/imgs/lesson__2.svg" alt="">
                        <p class="lessons__years">14-19 лет</p>
                        <h2 class="lessons__title">Для<br>
                            подростков</h2>
                        <a class="lessons__link" href="#">Узнать больше <svg width="26.200195" height="9.003906" viewBox="0 0 26.2002 9.00391" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                            <defs/>
                            <path id="Vector 156" d="M0.5 4.50195L25.5 4.50195M21.5786 8.50195L25.5 4.50195L21.5786 0.501953" stroke="#585165" stroke-opacity="1.000000" stroke-width="1.000000"/>
                        </svg>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="lessons__block-small">
                        <p class="lessons__years">Хит</p>
                        <h2 class="lessons__title">Подготовка<br> к ЗНО</h2>
                        <a class="lessons__link" href="#">Узнать больше <svg width="26.200195" height="9.003906" viewBox="0 0 26.2002 9.00391" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                            <defs/>
                            <path id="Vector 156" d="M0.5 4.50195L25.5 4.50195M21.5786 8.50195L25.5 4.50195L21.5786 0.501953" stroke="#585165" stroke-opacity="1.000000" stroke-width="1.000000"/>
                        </svg>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="lessons__blocks">
                    <div class="lessons__block-high">
                        <img class="lesson__image" src="static/imgs/lessons__high.svg" alt="">
                        <p class="lessons__years">8-14 лет</p>
                        <h2 class="lessons__title">Занятия<br>
                            для школьников</h2>
                        <a class="lessons__link" href="#">Узнать больше <svg width="26.200195" height="9.003906" viewBox="0 0 26.2002 9.00391" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                            <defs/>
                            <path id="Vector 156" d="M0.5 4.50195L25.5 4.50195M21.5786 8.50195L25.5 4.50195L21.5786 0.501953" stroke="#585165" stroke-opacity="1.000000" stroke-width="1.000000"/>
                        </svg>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="lessons__block-small">
                        <img class="lesson__image" src="static/imgs/lesson__2.svg" alt="">
                        <p class="lessons__years">14-19 лет</p>
                        <h2 class="lessons__title">Для<br>
                            подростков</h2>
                        <a class="lessons__link" href="#">Узнать больше <svg width="26.200195" height="9.003906" viewBox="0 0 26.2002 9.00391" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                            <defs/>
                            <path id="Vector 156" d="M0.5 4.50195L25.5 4.50195M21.5786 8.50195L25.5 4.50195L21.5786 0.501953" stroke="#585165" stroke-opacity="1.000000" stroke-width="1.000000"/>
                        </svg>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="lessons__block-small">
                        <img class="lesson__image" src="static/imgs/lesson__2.svg" alt="">
                        <p class="lessons__years">14-19 лет</p>
                        <h2 class="lessons__title">Для<br>
                            подростков</h2>
                        <a class="lessons__link" href="#">Узнать больше <svg width="26.200195" height="9.003906" viewBox="0 0 26.2002 9.00391" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                            <defs/>
                            <path id="Vector 156" d="M0.5 4.50195L25.5 4.50195M21.5786 8.50195L25.5 4.50195L21.5786 0.501953" stroke="#585165" stroke-opacity="1.000000" stroke-width="1.000000"/>
                        </svg>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Пора уже грид использовать.

Comment: Нужно именно на флексах

Comment: добавьте обертку для двух маленьких блоков